# Prove that the union of finite collection of compact sets is compact. In particular, a finite set is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

We are given that the definition of a set being compact as:

> A set $E ⊂ S$ is called compact if and only if every sequence in $E$ has an accumulation point in $E$.

And the definition of an accumulation point is:

> A point is called an accumulation point of a sequence $\{s_n\}$ if and only if for every $r > 0$ there are infinitely many $n ∈\mathbb{N}^+$ for which $s_n$ is in the open disc $D_r(s)$.

I understand that we can prove a set is compact by showing it can be covered by a finite open subcover, but I don't know how to prove it in using accumulation points. The terminology is confusing me. Would the proof still be the same?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the proof can't be literally "the same" if you want to do it with accumulation points, because you have to refer to accumulation points somehow! *But* it is possible to prove that a set is compact using the accumulation point definition if and only if it is compact using the open covers definition - it sounds like you might already have that theorem, in fact. If so, then proving it using open subcovers isn't "really" different. Just start your proof with "Since each of the sets in the union is compact, they meet the open-cover definition of a compact set", prove that the union satisfies the open-cover definition, and then finish with "By Theorem (whatever), a set satisfies the open-cover definition if and only if it satisfies the accumulation-point definition."

On the other hand, if for some reason you want to prove this *without* referring to open subcovers at all, it's still doable. Prove it the same way you prove anything - work with the definitions. So suppose we have sets $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ that are all compact, and we want to show that $A = \bigcup_{k\leq n}A_k$ is compact. We need to show that every sequence in $A$ has an accumulation point in $A$, so let $\{x_i\}$ be a sequence in $A$. Think about what can be said about the parts of this sequence that show up in each of the $A_k$ - in particular, notice that there has to be at least one $A_k$ that contains infinitely many $x_i$. Can you take it from there?

EDIT: Addressing your comments below:

First, we know there's at least one $A_k$ that contains infinitely many $x_i$ because of the Pigeonhole Principle - if you take infinitely many things and shove them into finitely many boxes, one of the boxes has infinitely many of them. That doesn't mean there's *only* one $A_k$ with infinitely many $x_i$, just that there's *at least one*.

Second, no, $A_k$ cannot be the accumulation point of anything, because it's not a point. You should review the definition of an "accumulation point" - basically, an accumulation point of a set is a point the set gets arbitrarily close to.

Third: We aim to show that the union contains at least one accumulation point - because that's what the definition of "compact" requires. We're not doing anything clever here, we're just showing that it meets the definition.

Fourth: Remember that (a) an accumulation point of a subsequence is an accumulation point of the whole sequence, and (b) for any sets $S$ and $T$, anything in $S$ is also in $S \cup T$, by definition. So if $A_k$ contains an accumulation point $x$ for the $x_i$'s that are in it, then $x$ is an accumulation point for the entire sequence and lies in $A$ automatically.

Comment: So, since we assume A1,A2,…,An are compact, we know that they each contain a sequence with infinitely many xi in order for each set to contain an accumulation point. Is this point xi the accumulation point of the union of the finite sets? Basically, I understand that each set contains an accumulation point, but how do you show that the union of the sets contains an accumulation point? Can we just assume the union does? And are we showing that the union contains one accumulation point or many accumulation points? Or do we just prove that at least one Ak that contains infinitely many xi?

Comment: How do we know that there is at least one Ak that contains infinitely many xi, and through showing that, does the mean Ak is the accumulation point of the union of sets, proving the union is compact?

Comment: @a.nas My response was too long, so I just added it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: So since there has to be at least one Ak with infinitely many xi, we can call an x among the xi's the accumulation point of Ak by the definition of an accumulation point, and since Ak has an accumulation point, the union of Ak with another set will share the same accumulation point by definition. Therefore, the whole set A has an accumulation point and by definition is compact. Is that the gist of it? Also, thank you so much for the help and in depth explanations, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @a.nas Well, $x$ need not be "among" the $x_i$'s; for example, if $x_i = 1/2^i$ for each $i$, the accumulation point $x$ is $0$, which is not $x_i$ for any $i$. Other than that, yes, you've got the idea now!